# Why does my for loop check only the first element?

Tags: java, for-loop, break

I have this method that checks the username and password of a user before login. Now my for loop checks only the first item, it finds that the first condition, `u.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("recruiter")` is not satisfied for the first item, so instead of going and checking the second item it just breaks and returns null.

Why does this happen?

Here is my method:

```
public User check(String userName, String password) throws AdException {

    try {
        begin();
        Query q = getSession().createQuery("from User");
        ArrayList<User> list = (ArrayList<User>) q.list();
        System.out.println("recruiterList is: " + list);

        for (User u: list) {
            System.out.println("Before if user is: " + u);

            if (u.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("recruiter")) {
                System.out.println("userName 1 is :" + u.getUserName());

                if (u.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && u.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase(password))
                    System.out.println("After if recruiter is: " + u);
                System.out.println("userName 2 is :" + u.getUserName());

                return u;
            }
            break;      
        }


    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        rollback();
        throw new AdException("Unfound " + userName, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: You have a `return` statement; your `if` must evaluate to `true` (or you `break`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
for (User u: list) {
    if (u.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("recruiter")) {

  //sysout

 if (u.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && u.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase(password))
          //2 sysout
        return u;
     }
     break;      //here break statement will exit your loop just after first Iteration.
 }
```

so try this code.

```
 for (User u: list) {
    if (u.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("recruiter")) {

  //sysout

 if (u.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && u.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase(password)){
          //2 sysout
        return u;
    } else{
               //your code if password doesnot matched
       }
      // continue even if more than one recruiter type User Object are in Database.
     }else{
               //your code if user Role doesnot matched
       }

 }   //loop will check all element present in that array. and if it's ROLE is  matched like "Recuriter" then it will check user and password.
```

Comment: Why do you add redundant continues? The loop will continue anyways.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I have added because if more logic if he needs to add to this specific code then he can also do that too.

It was just one kind of awareness for that you can add more code if you want to ..

Comment: At least address that in your answer, right now it just looks superfluous.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I have edited my answer. It was a mistake what i have does in hurry. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well it makes sense, since if you succeed you return and if you don't, you break, so it breaks:

```
for (User u: list) {
    System.out.println("Before if user is: " + u);
    if (u.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("recruiter")) {
        // code which returns at the end
        return u;
    }
    break;      
}
```

The `break;` statement is executed whenever the condition isn't met (otherwise you would `return` before you reach it), which is why you always check only the first item.

If you want to check all the items, simply remove the `break;` statement from your loop.

Comment: No, with or without the break it doesnt work. I know that the first item in my database doesnt meet the conditions so it should continue and check the 2nd item. I added  else{ continue;} statement and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

You use a `break` statement within the loop. This causes the loop to exit.

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed in the comments, you have only two alternatives in the loop, both make the loop to finish (on `return` or on `break`)  Just take off the `break;` statement or change it for a `continue;`.

By the way, why don't you `select from User where role = 'recruiter'` only?  This will make the roundtrip to the database server not to return all users, but only the ones that you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

Your code and logic are wrong. `u` doesn't change during an iteration of the `for-each` loop, it changes after each iteration. Your `println` statements suggest that you believe `u` is going to change during the first nested `if` statement. Since:

```
System.out.println("userName 1 is :" + u.getUserName());
```

and:

```
System.out.println("userName 2 is :" + u.getUserName());
```

appear in the same `if` block, nested in the `for-each` loop:

```
if (u.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("recruiter")) {
    System.out.println("userName 1 is :" + u.getUserName());

    if (u.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && u.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase(password))
        System.out.println("After if recruiter is: " + u);
    System.out.println("userName 2 is :" + u.getUserName());

    return u;
}
```

You also don't need to use a `break` or `continue` statement. You don't need a `break` statement because you have a `return` statement. You don't need a `continue` statement because that's what a loop does.

Note also that an `if` statement with no curly braces (`{ ... }`) only executes the line directly below it. For instance:

```
if (u.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && u.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase(password))
    System.out.println("After if recruiter is: " + u);
```

---

Your code should resemble:

```
public User check(String userName, String password) throws AdException {

    try {
        begin();
        Query q = getSession().createQuery("from User");
        ArrayList<User> list = (ArrayList<User>) q.list();
        System.out.println("recruiterList is: " + list);

        for (User u: list) {
            System.out.println("Before if user is: " + u);

            if (u.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("recruiter")) {
                System.out.println("userName 1 is :" + u.getUserName());

                if (u.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && u.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase(password)) {
                    System.out.println("After if recruiter is: " + u);
                    // System.out.println("userName 2 is :" + u.getUserName());

                    return u;
                }
            }    
        }

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        rollback();
        throw new AdException("Unfound " + userName, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

If you want to have a `println` statement that outputs what the current username's index is, then don't use a `for-each` use a regular `for` loop. For instance:

```
public User check(String userName, String password) throws AdException {

    try {
        begin();
        Query q = getSession().createQuery("from User");
        ArrayList<User> list = (ArrayList<User>) q.list();
        System.out.println("recruiterList is: " + list);

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Before if user is: " + u);

            if (u.getRole().equalsIgnoreCase("recruiter")) {
                System.out.println("userName " + (i + 1) + " is :" + u.getUserName());

                if (u.getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && u.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase(password)) {
                    System.out.println("After if recruiter is: " + u);

                    return u;
                }
            }    
        }

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        rollback();
        throw new AdException("Unfound " + userName, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```