# Loop throws exception before adding records

Tags: java, hibernate, loops, exception

I try to extract the `jobList` for a specific recruiter with "username". So everything executes good and I can print the recruiter username for the jobs I get from looping through the list. but the problem is that: `jobList.add(j)` is not executed and then it directly throws the hibernate exception. Does anyone know what the problem is?

I know I should be using appropriate queries but I get exceptions all the time, my database is very small (school project), so it doesn't matter now.

```
public List<Job> list(String userName) throws AdException {

    try {
        begin();
        Query q = getSession().createQuery("FROM Job");
        ArrayList<Job> list = (ArrayList<Job>) q.list();
        System.out.println("All Jobs: "+ list);

        ArrayList<Job> jobList = new ArrayList<Job>();

        for (Job j : list) {
            System.out.println("job userName is: "+ j.getRecruiter().getUserName());
            if (j.getRecruiter().getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase("userName")){

                jobList.add(j);
                System.out.println("jobList is: "+ jobList);
                return jobList;

            } else {
                continue;
            }

        }

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        rollback();
        throw new AdException("Could not get jobList for company: " + userName, e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: Post the full stack trace of the exception (add `e.printStackTrace()` to yourcatch clause to get it)

Comment: @JonnyHenly, [In hibernate it doesn't](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm)

Comment: The `else { continue; }` is redundant, like my answer says to your other quesiton: [Why does my for loop check only the first element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832340/why-does-my-for-loop-check-only-the-first-element/36832468#36832468)

Comment: I added the "e.printStackTrace();" but it's not executed because my method returns null

Comment: Which means this method is not causing the problem. What is probably causing the problem is related to `j.getRecruiter().getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase("userName")`, why are you comparing against the string literal `"userName"`? But if you fix this, then what happens if `null` is returned? That's where the true problem is.

Comment: @JonnyHenly: I know it's redundant but  for some reason it doesn't work without it!

Comment: It does, I promise : ) Look back at my answer to the question you asked earlier, linked in my comment above. You're explicitly telling the for loop to do what it already implicitly does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want userName to be quoted as a String Literal

```
if (j.getRecruiter().getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase("userName")){
```

but rather

```
if (j.getRecruiter().getUserName().equalsIgnoreCase(userName)){
```

**Edit**

As John so kindly mentions, your calling methos should also check for `null` being returned.

Comment: Even if he fixes that, what happens when `userName` doesn't match any `j.getRecruiter().getUserName()`? Him not handling this method returning null is probably where the true problem lies. I agree with your answer though : )

Comment: @JonnyHenly I have edited my answer with you advice.

Comment: Yes the mistake was in "username" instead of userName. Thanks a lot man!! You saved me! (sorry for the stupid mistake!)