# Issue with returning all values

Tags: java, class, junit

I am having trouble trying to return all the values in my Register class. Currently it only returns BLOGGS, J but should return JONES, F and SINGH, N also. Thank you in advance.

```
public static String execute(Register reg, Name n) {
  reg.removeName(1);
  reg.addName(n);
  for (Name nm : reg) {
    if(nm.getFamilyName().length() >= 5) {
      return (nm.getFamilyName().toUpperCase() + ", " + nm.getFirstName().charAt(0) + "\n");
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is the test code for the jUnit test

```
@Test
public void testExecute() {
    Register r = new Register();
    r.addName(new Name("Joe", "Bloggs"));
    r.addName(new Name("Fred", "Jones"));
    r.addName(new Name("Nila", "Singh"));       

    String result = RegisterApp.execute(r, new Name("Cassie", "Downturn"));

    String expectedResult = "BLOGGS, J\nSINGH, N\nDOWNTURN, C\n";

    assertEquals("The string returned should match the expected result (run 1)", expectedResult, result);
}
```

Comment: You're `returning` right away. I think you mean to add the found results to a list and return the list.

Comment: There must be a good dupe for this for Java. All I can find though is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36832340/why-does-my-for-loop-check-only-the-first-element. I don't really want to vote for it though, as it's a little convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

As @Carcigenicate already called out, you're returning right away from your for loop.

You could take advantage of stream api here:

```
public static String execute(Register reg, Name n) {
    reg.removeName(1);
    reg.addName(n);

    return 
        reg.stream()
           .filter(nm -> nm.getFamilyName().length() >= 5)
           .map(nm -> nm.getFamilyName().toUpperCase() + ", " + nm.getFirstName().charAt(0) + "\n")
           .collect(Collectors.joining());

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however i'm receiving an error saying stream() is undefined. I have already imported java.util.stream.Collectors. Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: What is the implementation of Register? If it is iterable then should be able to use stream api.